# Does XNA/OpenGL use left handed matrices?

Tags: opengl, math, matrix, xna

As I understand it, both OpenGL and XNA use a right-handed coordinate system by default.

But it looks as though the rotation matrices generated by both of these libraries are left-handed.

My reason for thinking this is that a positive Z rotation on either produces a matrix calculated like this (row major in this representation):

```
cos  |  sin  |  0
-sin |  cos  |  0
  0  |   0   |  1
```

And according to the sources I have found, this is a left-handed Z rotation matrix (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/rotationMatrices.html)

My questions are:

1. Am I correct? Are the matrices left handed but the coordinate system is right?
2. Is this true for all the matrix methods of XNA/OpenGL?
3. If I am correct, what does this matter? Why not make everything right-handed?

Comment: Rotation matrices are neither left-handed nor right-handed. The are universal for any handedness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In graphics APIs like OpenGL, there is not one single coordinate system. Vertices can be transformed multiple times while proceeding through the pipeline. Since a linear transformation is really the same thing as a change of coordinate systems, you can picture each transformation introducing a new coordinate system.

Based on this, applications can largely decide what coordinate system they want to work in. That's particularly true with the programmable pipeline used in current versions of OpenGL, but also to some degree with the legacy fixed pipeline.

Let me elaborate on some aspects of this, which should cover your questions for the case of OpenGL.

### Normalized Device Coordinates

Normalized Device Coordinates (NDC) is the coordinate system that vertices are in once vertex processing is finished. You could consider this the "native" 3D coordinate system of OpenGL. It has a range of [-1.0, 1.0] for all 3 coordinates, and is **left-handed**.

### Fixed Pipeline

In the legacy fixed pipeline, vertices are initially specified in *object coordinates* (see http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html). The modelview matrix transforms them to *eye coordinates*, which the projection matrix transforms to *clip coordinates*. After perspective division, they become NDC.

It is most common to use a right-handed coordinate system for the object coordinates. A modelview matrix that preserves handedness is used, which results in eye coordinates that are still right-handed. The projection matrix flips the direction of the z-axis, resulting in left-handed clip coordinates and NDC.

If you choose so, you can easily use left-handed object coordinates, and use a modelview matrix that flips handedness, so that you end up with right-handed eye coordinates again.

### Programmable Pipeline

With the programmable pipeline, you're at complete liberty to use any coordinate systems you want in your vertex shader. Say if your original vertices are specified in spherical coordinates, that's no problem at all. You just need to process them accordingly in the shader code. The vertex shader needs to produce clip coordinates (which as previously explained are left-handed) as output, but everything before that is completely open.

### Rotations

Current versions of OpenGL do not have any concept of rotations, or built-in features to create rotation matrices.

For the `glRotatef()` function used with the legacy fixed pipeline, the matrix is not what you have in the question. A rotation around the z-axis is defined by this matrix:

```
[ cos(a)  -sin(a)  0  0 ]
[ sin(a)  cos(a)   0  0 ]
[ 0       0        1  0 ]
[ 0       0        0  1 ]
```

You can find this matrix about halfway down on http://www.glprogramming.com/red/appendixf.html.

So this is a rotation matrix for a right-handed coordinate system. Which matches the common use I described above under "Fixed Pipeline".

### Answers to Numbered Questions

Based on this material, here are the answers to your numbered questions at the end:

1. No. Rotation matrices (at least as constructed by the deprecated fixed function API calls) are built to work with a right-handed coordinate system. While the "native" coordinate system (NDC) is left-handed.
2. For model transforms, it only makes a difference for rotations, which assume that they operate in a right-handed coordinate system. Projection matrices flip from right-handed to left-handed.
3. Left-handed vs right-handed matters for example if you're looking at the winding order of triangles, or if you're using cross products to calculate normals. Why NDC is left-handed... I don't know. It was defined like this at the beginning (I suspect that it might even have carried over from GL to OpenGL). And once it's defined one way, you can't change it anymore without breaking compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for a very complete answer!
This answers a lot.